# How to format numbers coming from an endpoint in my SwiftUI View?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm receiving data from my endpoint in this json format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "chapter_content_combined": "*1* No princípio Deus criou os céus e a terra. *2* Era a terra sem forma e vazia; trevas cobriam a face do abismo, e o Espírito de Deus se movia sobre a face das águas. *3* Disse Deus: \"Haja luz\", e houve luz. *4* Deus viu que a luz era boa, e separou a luz das trevas....",
        "chapter": 1,
        "verses_amount": 31,
        "book": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "chapter_content_combined": "*1* Assim foram concluídos os céus e a terra, e tudo o que neles há. *2* No sétimo dia Deus já havia concluído a obra que realizara, e nesse dia descansou. *3* Abençoou Deus o sétimo dia e o santificou, porque nele descansou de toda a obra que realizara na criação....",
        "chapter": 2,
        "verses_amount": 25,
        "book": 1
    },
]
```

And then I'm just outputting it in my View like this:

```
List {
  ForEach(self.viewModel.chapters) { chapter in
    Text(chapter.chapter_content_combined)
  }
}
```

The output in the canvas looks like this:

[image]

How can I format the `**` parts from the JSON (all numbers, `*1*, *2*, *3*` etc) to be superscripted (and colored), kinda like this:

(notice the orange, tiny superscript numbers):

[image]

I assume I'm gonna have to tap into UIKit for this, not sure how to proceed

I did manage to use Regex to filter out the `**` parts, but not sure how to proceed with it, or if there is a better approach

```
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\*([^\\*]*)\\*", options: .caseInsensitive) {
    let modChapter = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: chapter, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length:  chapter.count), withTemplate: "") // not sure what to do with this though
    print(modChapter)
}
```

Comment: Look into attributed strings and markdown

Comment: Should've specified that I need it for versions earlier than iOS 15.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses RegEx capture groups to determine where the superscript items are and then transforms them into concatenated SwiftUI `Text` objects:

```
struct Chapter : Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id : Int
    var chapter_content_combined : String
}

let chapters : [Chapter] = [.init(id: 0, chapter_content_combined: "*1* No princípio Deus criou os céus e a terra. *2* Era a terra sem forma e vazia; trevas cobriam a face do abismo, e o Espírito de Deus se movia sobre a face das águas. *3* Disse Deus: \"Haja luz\", e houve luz. *4* Deus viu que a luz era boa, e separou a luz das trevas...."),.init(id: 1, chapter_content_combined: "*1* Assim foram concluídos os céus e a terra, e tudo o que neles há. *2* No sétimo dia Deus já havia concluído a obra que realizara, e nesse dia descansou. *3* Abençoou Deus o sétimo dia e o santificou, porque nele descansou de toda a obra que realizara na criação....")]

enum TextType {
    case superscript(String)
    case normal(String)
}

func transformInput(input : String) -> [TextType] {
    var results : [TextType] = []
    
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count)
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\*(\\d+)\\*([^\\*]*)")
    regex.matches(in: input, options: [], range: range).forEach { match in
        guard let superscriptRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: input), let contentRange = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: input) else {
            return
        }
        
        results.append(.superscript(String(input[superscriptRange])))
        results.append(.normal(String(input[contentRange])))
    }
    return results
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ViewBuilder func formattedText(input : String) -> some View {
        let segments = transformInput(input: input).map { textType -> Text in
            switch textType {
            case .superscript(let str):
                return Text(str)
                    .font(.system(size: 10.0))
                    .baselineOffset(6.0)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            case .normal(let str):
                return Text(str)
            }
        }
        VStack {
            segments.reduce(Text(""), { $0 + $1 })
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(chapters) { chapter in
            formattedText(input: chapter.chapter_content_combined)
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in:

[image]

---

Note that you may have to edit the `guard` clause in the event that there are formatting scenarios with the capture groups not encountered in your sample input.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try out this answer? Did it work for you?

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm happy to remove this if it wasn't helpful, but it really does seem to address your issue. I see you're asking new questions, so I'm a bit confused as to why this didn't warrant a response at all.

Comment: Nice answer (voted)! Any way to get rid of the asterisks though?

Comment: @aheze thanks, and good catch. Yes, I've updated the capture group in the regex so that the asterisks are excluded.